# Proof related to eigenvalues and minimal polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, minimal-polynomials

I am having some doubts related to the proof's steps of the following statement:

Let $A \in K^{n\times n}$, and let $m_A$ the minimal polynomial of $A$. Let $\lambda \in K$. Then $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if and only if $\lambda$ is a root of $m_A$.

My doubt is with the $\implies$ of the proof:

$\implies$ Let $\lambda \in K$ an eigenvalue of $A$. By the division algorithm in $K[X]$ there exist $Q \in K[X]$ and $R \in K[X]$ such that $m_A=Q(X-\lambda)+R$.

Then $0=m_A(A)=Q(A)(A-\lambda I_n)+RI_n$. As $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then there is $v \in K^n$, $v \neq 0$ such that $Av=\lambda v.$ So $0=Q(A)(A-\lambda I_n)v+Rv=Q(A)(Av-\lambda v)+Rv=Q(A)0+Rv=Rv$, this means $Rv=0$, as $v \neq 0 \implies R=0$. It follows $m_A=Q(X-\lambda)$, i.e., $\lambda$ is a root of $m_A$.

This proof is pretty clear but there is one little step I couldn't follow: "By the division algorithm in $K[X]$ there exist $Q \in K[X]$ and $R \in K[X]$ such that $m_A=Q(X-\lambda)+R$." Why is $R$ necessarily in $K$ instead of $K[X]$? I would appreciate if someone could clarify/justify me this simple step.

Comment: You are dividing by a linear polynomial, so the remainder will be a constant.

Comment: Actually you don't need Euclidean division here at all. If $v\neq0$ is an eigenvector of$~A$ for$~\lambda$, you have $0=m_A[A]\cdot v=m_A[\lambda]v$ (this just uses $A^k\cdot v=\lambda^kv$ and linearity), so $m_A[\lambda]=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Euclidean division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) of a polynomial $P$ by $B$ states: there's $(Q,R)\in\Bbb (\Bbb K[X])^2$  such that 
$$P=QB+R$$
with $\boxed{\deg R<\deg B}$ and in the given proof $\deg(X-\lambda)=1$ so $\deg R<1$ and then $R$ is a constant in $\Bbb K$.

Comment: Of course! I've totally missed that in a sort of mental lapse, thanks very much.

Comment: You're welcome.