# Complex matrices with different properties

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A, B$ be $n \times n$ complex matrices. Prove that if $A$ is normal and $B$ is nilpotent such that $A + B = I_{n}$, then $A = I_{n}$

**Solution:**

I don't have any idea actually...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $B = I_n - A$ and $B$ is nilpotent, $(A-I_n)^m = 0$ for some $m$. Thus the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $(t-1)^m$. That is, $1$ is the only eigenvalue of $A$. Recall that $A$ is diagonalizable as it is normal. Thus there exists (unitary) matrix $U$ such that $UAU^{-1} = \mbox{diag}(1, \cdots, 1)=I_n$. Now $$I_n = UI_nU^{-1} = U(A+B)U^{-1} = UAU^{-1} + UBU^{-1} =I_n + UBU^{-1}$$
Hence $UBU^{-1} = 0$ and $B=0$.

Comment: That's so clever! Thanks!

Comment: "Thus the minimal polynomial of A divides (t−1)m. That is, 1 is the only eigenvalue of A." what do you mean?

Comment: @beingmathematician Since $(t-1)^m$ anihilates $A$, the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $(t-1)^m$ by definition. Thus it looks like $(t-1)^k$. Moreover, if $\lambda \in \mathbb C$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $t-\lambda$ is a factor of the minimal polynomial of $A$. (See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/822351/proof-related-to-eigenvalues-and-minimal-polynomial).) Now the conclusion follows.